# Azure Function not running with failure message as "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

Out of blue, I am getting below error when trying to run azure function app url from browser. When i started to explore about issue , I found a few check list .

1. checked `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` using same storage accounts.
2. Not deployed azure function app for couple of days.

Unable to get issue details from Kudo/console. When i try to hit from app service editor, i am receiving `Internal Server Error`

I am still unable find root cause for this issue.

[image]

[image]

App Settings of function app:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AppConfigEndpoint",
    "value": "https://test-euw-onlineservicehub-appconfig.azconfig.io",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AppConfigEnvironmentName",
    "value": "dev",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
    "value": "INSTRUMENTKEYUSED",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobs.FetchNotificationCodes.Disabled",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobs.FetchProfileCodes.Disabled",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobs.SendNotification.Disabled",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "value": "STORAGECONNECTINGSTRING",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "dotnet",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "NotificationsTopicName",
    "value": "notificationdetails-sbt",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
    "value": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=dev-euw-osh-backend-kv;SecretName=ServiceBusConnectionString)",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
    "value": "STORAGECONNECTINGSTRINGSAMEASUSEDINAzureWebJobsStorage",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
    "value": "dev-euw-osh-shared-func",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE",
    "value": "UTC",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

**I had done recently some setting to storage account:**

1. Changed Permitted scope for copy operation from Any storage account to storage account with in same Azure AD tenant.( storage account -->configuration). All my azure functions resides in same tenant.
2. File share max compatibility. - Changed security profile from Maximum compatibility to maximum security.(Storage account-->File Shares -- > Maximum Security)
3. unchecked Cross-tenant replication in Storage account-->Object replication-- > Advance Settings-->uncheck
4. soft delete enabled.

Note: I developed azure functions using .NET6 with  `C#` language.

Comment: have you checked this: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2759

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio yes. I have all those settings configured and never been changed past 2 months.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, please provide application settings of your functionapp.

Comment: @PravallikaKV updated my post

Comment: Can you try creating a new storage account and update the app settings accordingly.

Comment: Did you regenerate the keys in storage account by any chance? If yes try updating the connection string in app settings.

Comment: @PravallikaKV I had updated my post with the security changes i had changes recently.  Never changed any keys. Do you think that causing/breaking. i am not able to create azure function also with the same storage account.

Comment: Yes that could be the issue, can you update connection strings in the app settings and check.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the credentials/connection strings being used by your Azure Function app are valid and have the necessary permissions to access the storage account.

This issue mostly occurs if there are any changes made to the storage account.

- If you have made any changes to ***storage account***, you have to update the ***connection strings*** in the *App settings of function app* as mentioned in the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6513).
- Try ***re-deploying*** your function App.
- Create a ***new storage account*** and try to update the ***connection string*** and other related values accordingly in the ***App Settings*** of function app.
- Check the logs in `Functionapp=>Application insights=>Logs` for detailed error message:

[image]

- You can also check the logs in `Function App=>LogStream` as well.

[image]

**References:**

[Azure Function deploy fails with The user name or password is incorrect · Issue #6513 · microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6513)